# Macros and calories for a cut

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition, calories, cutting

I've been on an extended bulk for almost 2 years now. I used to be very skinny, just over 70kg at a height of 6'2, I'm now about 88kg. My body fat percentage isn't massive, about 12-13% but after my cut I want to be in the 8-10% range. My maintenance calories is 3500 and at least 3800 when bulking with a macro split of 500-180-120. I'm looking for advice on an ideal calorie deficit and macro split for a mild cut.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are most likely **grossly** underestimating your body fat percentage. 12% is already extremely lean, and getting below 10% is neither sustainable, nor healthy. Dropping 5kg to 83kg@8% would have you ready to walk on stage and compete for a pro card in body building. Are you *sure* you’re actually that lean?

Comment: Yes I've used bf% testers at a few different gyms and they have consistently told me I'm between 12&13 percent. What would you say is the lowest sustainable bf%?

Comment: have you checked this Q&A? https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40168/how-to-calculate-how-much-macros-fibre-and-calories-i-need-per-day?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

First off, 12-13% body fat percentage is extremely lean... unless you're prepping for a competition you shouldn't want to stay under 10% body fat percentage.

That being said, if you still want to attain this, you have to first decide how long you want your cut to be. For a longer, less aggressive cut try being 100-200 cals below maintenance. For a short and aggressive cut try being around 400 cals below maintenance.

If you are sure your maintenance is 3500 cals, you would want to aim at around 3200-3300 for an average cut. Of course, maintenance calories differ with how much cardio/steps you do per day, so try to take those into consideration.

Hope this helped.